# Calculate the revenue by year and by month based on details from another table between a startdate and endate

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

In a customer table, I have information about each customer and their subscription type. The table also shows when the subscription/membership began and when the next payment is due based on the subscription/membership type. Below is the table sample -

**Customer Table:**

| Customer_ID | Charge_ID | Membership_Type | Membership_StartDate | Membership_EndDate | Membership_Status | Next_Payment_Date | Gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cus_OzcGFMWjj7e6wf | ch_3OBd1JJuo27Vzw6d0tzOgF7c | Membership £216 Yearly | 2023-11-12 | NULL | Active | 2024-11-12 | £216.00 |
| cus_OynI9WYzFKG7ZJ | ch_3OApgkJuo27Vzw6d0bOJgdYf | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023-11-10 | NULL | Active | 2023-12-10 | £5.00 |
| cus_OzAOs3xIx4p3vd | ch_3OBC21Juo27Vzw6d1AGyK9LQ | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023-11-11 | NULL | Active | 2023-12-11 | £5.00 |
| cus_OzXKT687CWwQuS | ch_3OBYFiJuo27Vzw6d1FmiNkGm | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023-11-12 | NULL | Active | 2023-12-12 | £5.00 |
| cus_OzNXmqgA4I7zy2 | ch_3OBOkMJuo27Vzw6d0neOzJ13 | Membership £10 Monthly | 2023-11-11 | NULL | Active | 2023-12-11 | £10.00 |

My next step is to create a new table called Revenue, which should contain the following information. Depending on the type of subscription or membership, this table shows earned and deferred revenue for each customer by year and month.
**How can I achieve the below table on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool?**

**Revenue Table:**

| Customer_ID | Customer_Name | Membership_Type | Year | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cus_OzcGFMWjj7e6wf | ch_3OBd1JJuo27Vzw6d0tzOgF7c | Membership £216 Yearly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 11.21311475 | 18.29508197 |
| cus_OzcGFMWjj7e6wf | ch_3OBd1JJuo27Vzw6d0tzOgF7c | Membership £216 Yearly | 2024 | 18.29508197 | 17.1147541 | 18.29508197 | 17.70491803 | 18.29508197 | 17.70491803 | 18.29508197 | 18.29508197 | 17.70491803 | 18.29508197 | 6.491803279 | NULL |
| cus_OynI9WYzFKG7ZJ | ch_3OApgkJuo27Vzw6d0bOJgdYf | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3.5 | 1.5 |
| cus_OzAOs3xIx4p3vd | ch_3OBC21Juo27Vzw6d1AGyK9LQ | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3.333333333 | 1.666666667 |
| cus_OzXKT687CWwQuS | ch_3OBYFiJuo27Vzw6d1FmiNkGm | Membership £5 Monthly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3.166666667 | 1.833333333 |
| cus_OzNXmqgA4I7zy2 | ch_3OBOkMJuo27Vzw6d0neOzJ13 | Membership £10 Monthly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6.666666667 | 3.333333333 |
| cus_P087tismWgTMyM | ch_3OC7qDJuo27Vzw6d0hOuCQT2 | Membership £54 Yearly | 2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2.454545455 | 4.227272727 |
| cus_P087tismWgTMyM | ch_3OC7qDJuo27Vzw6d0hOuCQT2 | Membership £54 Yearly | 2024 | 4.227272727 | 3.954545455 | 4.227272727 | 4.090909091 | 4.227272727 | 4.090909091 | 4.227272727 | 4.227272727 | 4.090909091 | 4.227272727 | 4.090909091 | 1.636363636 |

1. My first step was to create a script to calculate the revenue amount for an individual customer. To explain my script below I took details of customer_id - cus_OzcGFMWjj7e6wf as an input to this script. If you can help me figure out how to use the below script for each customer in my customer table to create my revenue table, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
declare @Membership_StartDate date;
declare @Membership_EndDate date;
declare @Gross INT;

set @Membership_StartDate = '2023-11-12';
set @Membership_EndDate = '2024-11-12';
set @Gross = 216.000000;

With FirstQuery AS
(
select year(dt) [Year], month(dt) [Month], count(*) NumberofDays
from (select top(datediff(d, dateadd(dd,-1,@Membership_StartDate), dateadd(dd,-1,@Membership_EndDate))) dateadd(d, row_number() over (order by (select null)), dateadd(dd,-1,@Membership_StartDate)) dt
from sys.columns) q
group by year(dt), month(dt)
)   
select Year
    , Jan = MAX(case when Month = 1 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Feb = MAX(case when Month = 2 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Mar = MAX(case when Month = 3 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Apr = MAX(case when Month = 4 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , May = MAX(case when Month = 5 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Jun = MAX(case when Month = 6 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Jul = MAX(case when Month = 7 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Aug = MAX(case when Month = 8 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Sep = MAX(case when Month = 9 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Oct = MAX(case when Month = 10 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Nov = MAX(case when Month = 11 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)
    , Dec = MAX(case when Month = 12 then (1.0*NumberofDays)/(1.0*DATEDIFF(day, @Membership_StartDate, @Membership_EndDate))*(1.0*@Gross) end)    
from FirstQuery
group by Year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we reimagine your tables to be relational, this is a fairly straightforward pivot.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (CustomerID INT IDENTITY, FirstName NVARCHAR(50), LastName NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Customers (FirstName, LastName) VALUES 
('James','Kirk'), ('Leonard','McCoy'), ('Montgomery','Scott'), ('Nyota','Uhura');

DECLARE @CustomerMemberships TABLE (CustomerID INT, MembershipType INT, Active BIT, BillCycle TINYINT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @CustomerMemberships (CustomerID, MembershipType, Active, BillCycle, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
(1,1,1, 10, '2024-01-01', '2024-12-31'), (2,1,1, 11, '2024-01-01', '2025-06-30'), (3,2,1, 12, '2025-01-01', '2026-03-31'), (4,3,1, 5, '2024-01-01', '2030-12-31');

DECLARE @Memberships TABLE (MembershipType INT IDENTITY, MembershipName NVARCHAR(50), AnnualBilling BIT, MonthlyBilling BIT, Cost DECIMAL(10,3));
INSERT INTO @Memberships (MembershipName, AnnualBilling, MonthlyBilling, Cost) VALUES
('Monthly Basic', 0, 1, 5.00), ('Monthly Premium', 0, 1, 10.00), ('Annual Basic', 1, 0, 216);

;WITH Dates AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()) AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,Date)
  FROM Dates
 WHERE Date < '2030-12-01'
), Revenue AS (
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,Date), DATEPART(MONTH,Date), 1) AS Month,
       CASE WHEN AnnualBilling = 1 THEN m.Cost / 12.0
            WHEN MonthlyBilling = 1 THEN m.Cost
        END AS Cost, c.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, m.MembershipName
  FROM @Customers c
    CROSS APPLY Dates y
    INNER JOIN @CustomerMemberships cm
      ON c.CustomerID = cm.CustomerID
      AND y.Date BETWEEN cm.StartDate AND CM.EndDate
    INNER JOIN @Memberships m
      ON cm.MembershipType = m.MembershipType
)
SELECT *
  FROM (

        SELECT FirstName, LastName, DATEPART(YEAR,Month) AS Year, DATENAME(MONTH,Month) AS Month, Cost
          FROM Revenue
         WHERE Month IS NOT NULL
       ) a
    PIVOT (
           SUM(Cost) FOR Month IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
          ) p;
```

| FirstName | LastName | Year | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Kirk | 2024 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 |
| Leonard | McCoy | 2024 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 |
| Leonard | McCoy | 2025 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 | 5.0000000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Montgomery | Scott | 2025 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 |
| Montgomery | Scott | 2026 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 | 10.0000000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2024 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2025 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2026 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2027 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2028 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2029 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |
| Nyota | Uhura | 2030 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 | 18.0000000 |

The table objects described at the top of this script are relational and can describe the relationship between a customer, their membership and membership types. You can consider each of the columns as distinct properties of those objects.

In the `COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION` (CTE) 'Dates' we're producing a row for each month between now and the end of the period (2023-12-01). In the following `CTE` Revenue we prepare the data to be consumed by a pivot, producing a row for each month a customer has a membership, and determining the amount of attributable revenue they have - for monthly plans we just take the cost. For annual plans we take the cost divided by 12.

Finally, we perform the pivot on the revenue `CTE` to produce a data set which contains a column for each month that we have data for, for each customer and each year they have an active subscription.

I would strongly suggest you don't use strings for your identifiers, or if you must, also include a numeric surrogate key.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Recursive common table expressions are not supported on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool, could you please help

Comment: Build your self a calendar table to take it's place. You can then just select the days/weeks/months you need.